# Replacing values in a column using values in a list

Tags: python, pandas

This might already be answered in stack and I just don't know the best way to phrase this question. But I'm trying to go through a column (data["Id"]) in a DataFrame (data) that contains incomplete strings and replace them with completed versions that I have in a list.

I can't make the switch outright by just reassigning the column values with the list values because the values in the column are randomly ordered and they are connected to other column values in the dataframe that are important.

I tried doing this:

```
for img_name in images_list:
    for label in data["Id"]:
        if label in img_name:
            data["Id"] = data["Id"].replace(label,img_name)
```

But my list values and column values are quite large (120,000 each) so this method would take forever. I was wondering if anyone knows a better way of going about this problem? I apologize in advance if this question is redundant and would much a appreciate a link that answers this question.

**List Example:**

["0img1_type1.png","1img1_type2.png","2img1_type3.png"]

**data["Id"] Example:**

["0img1","1img1","2img1"]

Comment: When you say 'column', are you referring to a dataframe from pandas?

Comment: Yes, sorry just made the change

Comment: It'll help a lot if you also post an example of your list and values to replace in the dataframe.

Comment: BTW, you can consider using a generator where it stops searching the list when it has found a match rather than always scanning the whole list. Just thought of it.

Comment: @BernardL could you provide an example of how you would apply a generator in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["0img1","1img1","2img1"]]).T
df.columns = ['id']

l = ["0img1_type1.png","1img1_type2.png","2img1_type3.png"]
l = set(l)

df['id'] = df['id'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in l if x in i][0])
df
```

It basically retrieves the first value from your list that matches a substring in your column values. For faster lookup, it is better to convert your `list` into `set`.

Comment: I'm trying to use this method, but I'm noticing a similar problem to the previous method in terms of run time. I have 120,000 data values in both the list and the column. This method is probably faster than the embedded loop (haven't compared the run times yet)  but is it possible to improve your method to make the switch more time efficient? If so, how would you do it?

Comment: I actually don't think it will take that long. In terms of lookup I don't think there are many other ways to do it faster. If your data is referring to your example, it might be better off adding the additional strings to your column values.

Comment: "Embed Loop" Time: 11min 15s; "Apply Lambda" Time: 7min 11s

Comment: Well hope it helped. :)